# Can you get your current speed using ARKit?

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

I have few related questions.

1) Can you get the position of the device in the global coordinates? I tried to get this value using ARFrame.camera.transform.colums.3, but it seems like the [X,Y,Z] in this column is alway [0,0,0]. I interpreted this transform to be the camera's orientation with respective to the body frame. Can someone explain what exactly you get out of the ARFrame.camera.transform?

2) If we have the position of the device (camera) in the global coordinates, I assume we can easily get the velocity of the device. Is this a valid statement?

3) Can you only get the global position when you are tracking an object? Thus, you get your position relative to the tracked object? I would like to get the speed of the device even when the camera shakes a lot, thus the tracking quality is not always good.

Comment: I dont know how the ARKit works but i think what you are trying to achieve can be achieved using the GPS pretty much like the running apps do it, they use gps to track your distance and the time taken and give an average speed. But i think you are trying something else, in that context the 3rd point seems valid to me, to track speed of object relative to another object makes sense. It wouldnt be possible to calculate speed unless you know the distance and time, which is missing here.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)).  By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323395)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can make a speedometer with ARKit. [A few people have already.](https://mobile.twitter.com/chendo/status/880319424728674304)

Regarding your more specific questions...

1. ARKit doesn’t have “global coordinates”, or probably not in the sense you’re thinking. Camera and anchor transforms use a shared reference frame (“world” space in traditional 3D graphics parlance), but that reference frame is valid only within the session: `0,0,0` is where your camera/device was at the beginning of the session.
2. If you have two positions at two different times in any shared reference frame, the difference between those positions is the average velocity over that time.
3. ARKit doesn’t track objects. The camera transform is always relative to “world” space. As mentioned above, it’s `0,0,0` at the beginning of your session because the reference frame is based within the session.

If you want Global positioning — that is, relative to the Earth — you should be looking at Core Location. Note that there’s a difference of scale and precision, though: GPS is accurate to a meter or two but operates at planet scale, and ARKit is accurate to a centimeter or two but operates at room scale.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, but I still don't understand how I can get the positions to not read [0,0,0]. Do you have more insight on how I can get speed from ARKit?